# How can I keep user scores inside my iPhone App?

Tags: iphone

I'm working on a game, but I'm having trouble trying to **set the scores and keeping them in a table**. What I've done is I've made it to where my **game runs a method at the end of every level to check whether the score should be saved or not**, but I'm not sure how to save them and sort them from **highest to lowest**.

This is what my table should include:

- **#:**
- **Name:**
- **Score:**
- **Time:**

In that order, I've also sorted it to only include 14 rows.

What I have on the XIB is a scrollview with an image inside that shows the chart and the top fields **[#: , Name: , Score: , Time: ]**. I'm not sure how I should display the text for the fields though.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me **how I would go about making this** and keeping up with the sorting and everything to display them in the table.

[image: Scores]

Here's my code so far, but it's subject to change, so feel free to correct me where I'm wrong or provide me with a different solution.

Thanks in advance!

```
-(void) mGameScoreSelected {
    if (![sGameScoresScore isEqualToString:@""]) {
        sScoresRowCurrent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i | %@ | %@ | %@", iGameScoresPlace,sGameScoresName, sGameScoresScore, sGameScoresTime];

        kLog(@"%@", sScoresRowCurrent);
    }
}

-(void) mGameScoreDetermine {
    bGameScoreSetFinished = TRUE;

    for (int x = 0; x <= 3*14; x++) {
        if ([sGameScoresScore intValue] > [sScoresScores [x-1] intValue] && bGameScoreSetFinished == TRUE) {
            [self mGameScoreSelected];
            bGameScoreSetFinished = FALSE;
        } else {
            sGameScoresScore = @"";
            sGameScoresTime = @"";
        }
    }
}

-(void) mGameScoreSet {    
    sGameScoresScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", iGameScoreCurrent];
    sGameScoresTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", iGameTimeTotal - iGameTimeCurrent];

    kLog(@"Score: %@", sGameScoresScore);
    kLog(@"Time: %@", sGameScoresTime);

    [self mGameScoreDetermine];
}

-(void) mGameEnded {
    [self mGameScoreSet];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a perfect solution to my problem. What I did is I used an `NSMutableArray` to save the `Name`, `Score`, and `Time` in the same `NSString` like such: `@"Fer|2194|17"`. And then what I did is I sorted the array using the beautiful code below. Then I saved it to `NSUserDefaults` where it was loaded every time the app was launched.

**Sort Array**

```
-(void) logArray:(NSArray *)array sorted:(BOOL)sorted {
NSString * result = @"";

    if ([array count] != 0) {
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Items in array: %d", [array count]];
        result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"\nSorted: %s", (sorted ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")];

        if (sorted == TRUE) {
            array = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < [array count]; x++) {
            result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%d: %@", x, [array objectAtIndex:x]];
        }
    } else {
        result = @"No Items In Array";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

**NSUserDefaults**

```
-(void) saveObjectToUserDefaults:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:object forKey:key];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: I would recommend CoreData. `NSUserDefaults` should not be used like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Core Data programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html) and create your table there. Then you can use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch those objects and very easily display what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to save the application data on the iPhone, and this is discussed wonderfully in [OREILLY's post](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1633-how-to-store-iphone-app-data/) !

With regards to displaying them in the fields, you will need to implement the methods for retrieving information from your database and you can do it in many ways. You need to look at the [Core Data Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

It again depends on your needs. You can go with `NSUserDefaults` or the `sqlLite` for data storage. If you require the data to show up, if the user logins into another device, I would say - sync it up with web services !!!